# Unable to create Azure resources using terraform despite being a subscription owner

Tags: azure, terraform, privileges

I cannot create any resource in azure cloud using terraform.

WSL2 - Ubuntu:

```
             Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
```

Terraform version:

```
             Terraform v1.1.5
```

AZ CLI version:

```
            "azure-cli": "2.33.0"
            "azure-cli-core": "2.33.0"
            "azure-cli-telemetry": "1.0.6"
```

At the beggining I login to azure subscription through az login. I have only one available subscription on this account and I am owner.

Then I create "main.tf" file same as here :  https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs#example-usage

After "terraform init" i do "terraform plan" but i recive that error:

```
                     Error: Unable to list provider registration status, it is possible that this is due to invalid credentials or the service principal does not have permission to use the Resource Manager API, Azure error: resources.ProvidersClient#List: Failure sending request: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: Get "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/providers?api-version=2016-02-01": dial tcp: lookup management.azure.com on 000.00.000.0:00: cannot unmarshal DNS message

                     with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm"],
                     on main.tf line 10, in provider "azurerm":
                     10: provider "azurerm" {
```

Also i go through this way: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/service_principal_client_secret

My app has contributor/owner priviliges at the subscription level.

Then adding this configuration :

```
            provider "azurerm" {
               features {}
               subscription_id = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
               client_id       = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
               client_secret   = var.client_secret
               tenant_id       = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
            }
```

Finally I get the same error. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo vim /etc/resolv.conf
```

and change `nameserver` value to `8.8.8.8`

It should work, but every time you reboot you should do this action or write a script to automate it!

Comment: great! Any explanation why the WSL default nameserver cause the problem?